# php echo question

Tags: mysql, arrays, echo

```
$this->get_name = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($this->link,"SELECT complete_name FROM student WHERE email='$this->email'"));

mysqli_query($this->link, $this->drop_query) or die(mysql_error());

echo $this->get_name['complete_name'].  " has been marked as Left!";
```

when i run this i get the following:

"John has been marked as Left!"

but when i run

```
echo ".$this->get_name['complete_name'] has been marked as Left!";
```

i get this:

"Array['complete_name'] has been marked as Left!"

aren't they supposed to print the same stuff?

Answer (score 3):

PHP:s parser doesnt know where the variable ends in the second case, use {} to encapsulate the variable in the string

```
echo "{$this->get_name['complete_name']} has been marked as Left!";
```

Comment: Yep. Variable substitution without curly brackets only considers characters that are valid as parts of an identifier. Use curly brackets to explicitly delimit the substitution.

Comment: Docu: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the array offset use:

```
{$this->get_name['complete_name']}
```

Use of the brackets tells PHP to expect the entire containment to be used as the variable if possible.

See [PHP's String Parsing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) for more details. As part of their examples they have this example:

```
// Works, quoted keys only work using the curly brace syntax
echo "This works: {$arr['key']}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I'm echoing anything more complex than something like `$complete_name`, I don't include it in the quotes:

```
echo $this->get_name['complete_name'].' has been marked as Left!';
```

I find the ease of reading the whole quote as a sentence is lost anyways when dealing with objects and arrays, etc. So if you're looking to read the quoted line easily, I might suggest using:

```
$complete_name = $this->get_name['complete_name'];   # deal with the dirty stuff here 

echo "$complete_name has been marked as left!";      # so this is much easier to read
```

Comment: You shouldn't do this. You're making PHP work double duty by using double quotes AND concatenating. If you are going to do this, always use single quotes for strings.